# How to "resolve" foreign keys in SQLAlchemy query results?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've written a small tool that creates SQLAlchemy code from a written specification. The tool can create code like this:

```python
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('address.id'))

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

I can insert new records, I can query them, that works like a charm, but I would really like to not having to manually look for the Address of a Person.

I want to be able to access the address belonging to a specific person through the Person object. If I understand the examples correctly I need to do it like this (example based on http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#one-to-many-relationships)?

```python
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    address = db.relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

This looks to me all backwards, I have to give every Address a "link" to a Person and then backref so I can have an addresses for a person? Is this not possible to do directly from Person?

Also, creating code for this is much more complicated, so I'd really like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example the Person can have exactly 1 address, but each address can be used by multiple Persons.
In your second solution Person can now have multiple addresses, but each address is unique to a given Person (note that the ForeignKey moved tables).

So you went from N:1 to 1:N. By saying you want a list of the N-side, rather than the instance on the 1-side, you now have to specify more.

Comment: I know, that's why I ask. There are no 1:1 examples I can find and the 1:N examples all have that (to me) superfluous backref thing going on. I would like to know how to do 1:1 the easiest way possible so I don't have to do a second query for the Address when I have the Person.